# Executing a powershell script on a remote computer file system

Tags: windows, powershell

There is a powershell script located on the `C:\`. The script executes a .msu file.

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName [name] -FilePath C:\file.txt` doesn't work because it checks locally on your system for the file to pass over to execute.

I want a powershell script that executes another remote powershell script remotely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing a powershell script locally to run on a remote computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191859/executing-a-powershell-script-locally-to-run-on-a-remote-computer)

Comment: Just google it . Enable the PSRemoting and use `Invoke-Command -ComputerName <Computername> -credential <credentials> -FilePath $scriptPath\file.ps1`

Comment: `invoke-command { powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass c:\myscript.ps1 } -computername box1`

Answer (score 0):

If you use powershell 5 on both sides you could copy the file via:
$TargetSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName server

Copy-Item -ToSession $TargetSession -Path "c:\local\" -Destination "C:\remote\" -Recurse

You could also use copy to admin share c$

Comment: We are using PS v 2. We are trying to mass deploy an update script to 2000+ computers. So the run down is, I created a script to remotely enable winrm on each computer. This will allow us to use the invoke-command remotely. Now, we have a software tool that allows us to push and execute scripts (.bat, .msi, etc). However, it doesn't execute .ps1. So, the .bat script is `xcopy` two files onto the targets `C:\ `. This is where this script will come into play.

Comment: @schnipdip You are likely going to run into the [double hop problem](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/08/30/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely/)

Comment: @BenH I don't believe so. We aren't needing an authentication system. We have direct access to each user account without the need to be authenticated by an authentication server each time. If it does happen I will let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

And if you try this method?

Run this command on your local machine :

```
$computer = "COMP1"    
([WMICLASS]"\\$computer\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process").Create('C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -File "script.ps1"')
```

Comment: should this be run locally?

Comment: `cannot convert \\\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process to type "System.management.managementclass" error: invalid parameter`

Comment: Is the script stored on the remote machine?

Comment: The script is is stored on my computer. Then the microsoft script is stored on the end user root.