# Invoke-command Missing Expression Operator '-'

Tags: windows, powershell

```
invoke-command -computer hq128804 -scriptblock {powershell.exe -nonprofile -executionpolicy Bypass c:\Install-WMF5.ps1}
```

The Error:

```
Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Missing express...y operator '-'.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : hq128804

At line:1 char:2
+ - <<<< nonprofile -executionpolicy Bypass c:\Install-WMF5.ps1
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (-:String) [], ParentContainsErrorR
   ecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
NotSpecified: (:) [], RemoteException
```

I am trying to run a script that is located on the root file system of another remote PC. I want to be able to execute this and update PowerShell for 2000 machines. I have the update files on each system, I just need a way to execute the .ps1 file Microsoft provides from my machine.

Comment: The script you invoke (`Install-WMF5.ps1`) has an error - your code example seems good.

Comment: That is microsofts script....

Comment: Well - I was about to say "so? I had a script from M$ that could not work on W10 machines because of lazy coding...", but there must be another issue. Give me a second

Comment: Try without the typo `nonprofile -> NoProfile`

Comment: It is working... but it is hanging. It isn't producing an error or anything. I have executable rights. winrm is enabled.

Comment: I've encountered issues with remoting and handling windows updates. I could not get it to work with powershell remoting, so I recoded it to utilize `Win32_Process` class'  method `create` in CIM to make my code work. Maybe this is similar. Does the scirpt work if you execute it inside a rdp session?

Comment: @restless1987 : I already suggested him the same method in the same subject he opened twice... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394744/executing-a-powershell-script-on-a-remote-computer-file-system/44396457?noredirect=1#comment75796229_44396457

Comment: It may work. Could you add your code? I'd love to see how you did it.

Comment: Hahaha, this was to figure out an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing a powershell script on a remote computer file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394744/executing-a-powershell-script-on-a-remote-computer-file-system)

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
Invoke-command -ComputerName hq128804 -scriptblock{powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -Command "& { c:\Install-WMF5.ps1}" }
```

Note: Make sure you are having the ps1 properly placed in the mentioned path